# Authorization headers Silverlight WebClient

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight

I'm using WebClient to call a Web Service from another application, It's working actually but for some services I need to send Authorization Headers.
I have tried many things like this :

```
 string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
 req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
```

But Silverlight does not implement Encoding.ASCII and it's not working.

I have also tried this :

```
WebClient wc=new WebClient();
wc.Credentials=new NetworkCredentials("user","pass");
```

And it's not working...

I'm looking for some help here !

Comment: You should be able to use the equivalent UTF8 class instead of ASCII. But, could you please give more details about what is going wrong? Do you get an exception? Have you tried doing a server side WCF trace, or a client side HTTP trace with Fiddler?